# strftime on Heroku

Tags: php, heroku

Trying to get day of the week of a given date. Code is `strftime("%a", $date->getTimestamp())`
Locally this returns `Vrijdag` and on Heroku it returns `Friday`
Above the strftime I have a `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');` which should set it to Dutch and on Heroku I’ve set the timezone in the variables with `TZ=Europe/Amsterdam`.

How can I resolve the difference between local and Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

Only **English** locales are installed in Heroku by default.

But we can fix it in 3 steps:

1. Create a `.locales` file at your app's root, and put `nl_NL` in this file.
2. Add the locales buildpack to your app. Just execute command:
   `heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-locale`
3. Redeploy your application (just create small commit and push to heroku) and you must see something like this:
   [image]

Thats all! After that try to use `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');`